# How to handle and detect multiple button even of tableviewcell in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to change item-Button value on Plus and Minus Button click of tableviewcell.
This is my tableview cell for row index method code.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            CustomCell *cell = [menuTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            UIButton *minusBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            minusBtn.frame= CGRectMake(400, 5,30,30);
            minusBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [minusBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"removeButan.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [minusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(minusAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            UIButton *plusBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            plusBtn.frame= CGRectMake(500, 5,30,30);
            plusBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [plusBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Addbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [plusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(plusAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    

            UIButton *itemBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            itemBtn.frame= CGRectMake(450, 5,30,30);
            itemBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [itemBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"number_butan_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [itemBtn setTitle:totalItem forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [itemBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            UIButton *addToCart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            addToCart.frame= CGRectMake(580,5,30,30);
            addToCart.tag = indexPath.row;
            addToCart.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            [addToCart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [addToCart addTarget:self action:@selector(addToCartAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

            UIButton *infoBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            infoBtn.frame= CGRectMake(630, 5,30,30);
            infoBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [infoBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [infoBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(displayDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            // lblTitle.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.primaryLabel.text = [appDelegate.nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.secondaryLabel.text = [appDelegate.sortDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.priceLabel.text = [appDelegate.rateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:minusBtn];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:plusBtn];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:addToCart];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:itemBtn];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:infoBtn];

            return cell;
}


- (IBAction)plusAction:(id)sender{

   // Hat* obj = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
   // NSNumber* hatId = obj.idValue;

    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
    UITableView *table=(UITableView*)[cell superview];
    NSIndexPath *path=[table indexPathForCell:cell];

    int value = [totalItem intValue];
    value++;

    totalItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",totalItem]);
    [menuTableView reloadData];

}

- (IBAction)minusAction:(id)sender{

    UIView *contentView = [sender superview];

    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[[contentView superview] superview];
    UITableView *table=(UITableView*)[cell superview];
    NSIndexPath *path=[table indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSUInteger buttonRow = [[menuTableView
                             indexPathForCell:cell] row];

    int value = [totalItem intValue];
    value--;

    totalItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",totalItem]);
    [menuTableView reloadData];

}
```

i am trying this but not working.it change all row value

Comment: don't give same tag to all buttons give tag like 100+indexPath.row,200+indexPath.row,..

Answer (score 1):

You only have one instance of the totalItem.  If you have many rows and you want to store each one individually, you will need to create an array to store each of the individual rows and then display the appropriate value in the cellForRow method.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.

```
- (IBAction)plusAction:(id)sender{
    int correctIndex = [sender tag];
    int old = [[appDelegate.quantityArray objectAtIndex:correctIndex] intValue];
    [appDelegate.quantityArray replaceObjectAtIndex:correctIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:old + 1]];
    [menuTableView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)minusAction:(id)sender{
    int correctIndex = [sender tag];
    int old = [[appDelegate.quantityArray objectAtIndex:correctIndex] intValue];
    [appDelegate.quantityArray replaceObjectAtIndex:correctIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:old - 1]];
    [menuTableView reloadData]; 
}
```